# honor those whose lives were tragically stolen

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Tim Cook (Apple CEO) tweeted 2 days ago:

> This Transgender Day of Remembrance, we **honor those whose lives were tragically stolen** by bigotry and hatred. It’s only through love, acceptance and education that we can build a future where everyone is safe to live their truth.

The first sentence sounds rather abstract to me. Does "tragically stolen" here mean "died in the tragedy because being transgender had led to death in those days when some people harbored bigotry and hatred toward the transgenders and killed them"?

Comment: Your version is unnecessarily complicated. They had their lives stolen by being murdered by those who felt bigotry and hatred towards transgender people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means "those who were killed by bigots".

It includes both people who were murdered and people who committed suicide because of bigots and haters.

It possibly includes people who had their lives stolen as they were not able to live a happy life as they had to pretend to be a different gender to who they really were.

It isn't trying to be a scientifically precise statement.